# Google Maps SDK | Notification Api for Road Accidents Nearby

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4, xcode9

Ok, SO I have tried to look for an API in Google Maps and cannot find one which can provide me information about accidents that might have happened in a certain radius, road accidents of course. I wish to get all the accidents that are happening or have happened in the past for Google Maps. Is there any specific API or in general how could I get this information?

Comment: I think no one can walk around in the road and record the accidents for you. Maybe, the government can collect it by 911 or another ones but no way to get it.

Comment: @QuocNguyen yeah i understand what you're trying to say here, but what about how they manage to update the traffic jams and congested situations at a certain time period in the day?

Comment: The GG Traffic sometimes (many times) is not right. They collected the traffic data in a long time and make the detector.

Comment: @QuocNguyen well i discovered something, "https://developers.google.com/waze/data-feed/overview" and it explains how information can be provided to users via waze but then again its for web applications and not mobile devices. They do provide Waze SDK for certain users but that too requires Waze to be installed on the device, I however dont want to redirect to another application but provide the required functionality in my application